# Method's If condition based on list attributes

Tags: vb.net

I have function as below. I would like to make it bit more generic. Would like to be able to send parameters of datatable columns and expected values for each.

```
Private Function SearchDtValue(dt As DataTable, Value1 As String, Value2 As String) As String
   For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
       If row("Name") = Value1 And row("Age") = Value2 Then
          Return row("Surname")
       End If
   Next
   Return Nothing
End Function
```

In my new function which could get diffrent number of columns and their values to be checked for example i want to check 3 columns of datatable and say 3 expected values for each of to be compared. In this case it should look something as below:

**Psuedo code:**

```
SearchDtValue(dt as DataTable, dictionary(Of String, String),colNameValueToBeRetreived)
```

so dictionary (just for example) would contain column names and expected values for each of.
In our example when i send three of them it should construct method such this way:

e.g:

```
    Dictionary could contain:
    Age, 30
    Name, John
    Surname, Brzenk

colNameValueToBeRetreived= Address
```

Method would look like this based on paraemters:

```
  For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
       If row(Age) = "30" And row(Name) = "John" And row(Surname) = "Brzenk" Then
          Return row(colNameValueToBeRetreived)
       End If
   Next
```

Comment: is there a question here?

Comment: @user2366842 the question is how to do this

Comment: Conditional conditioning is not possible. You can't dynamically append "AND"s in your If condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code. Assumption Dictionary has key as columns names and value as expected column value for the key.

```
Private Function SearchDtValue(dt As DataTable, cols As Dictionary(Of String, String), colNameValueToBeRetreived As String) As String
    Dim returnValue As String = Nothing

    Try
        Dim matchCount As Integer = 0
        For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
            For Each col In cols
                If row(col.Key).ToString = col.Value Then
                    matchCount = matchCount + 1
                End If
            Next

            If matchCount = cols.Count Then
                returnValue = row(colNameValueToBeRetreived).ToString
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception("Error in matching column values")
    End Try

    Return returnValue

End Function
```